How do I install MLC-LLM with Poetry instead of Conda?
The installation instructions are here: https://llm.mlc.ai/docs/install/mlc_llm.html#install-mlc-packages
I added the source to the .pytoml file as follows.
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "mlc"
url = "https://mlc.ai/wheels"
priority = "primary"

Here is what happens when I try running one of the suggestions by the chatbot.
ceti@ceti16:~/inference-servers$ poetry add mlc-llm-nightly-cu123 mlc-ai-nightly-cu123 --allow-prereleases --source mlc

Could not find a matching version of package mlc-llm-nightly-cu123

I also tried using the direct links, but it's refusing to accept them.
ceti@ceti16:~/inference-servers$ poetry add https://github.com/mlc-ai/package/releases/download/v0.9.dev0/mlc_ai_nightly_cu123-0.18.dev225-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.3s)

Because mlc-ai-nightly-cu123 (0.18.dev225) @ https://github.com/mlc-ai/package/releases/download/v0.9.dev0/mlc_ai_nightly_cu123-0.18.dev225-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl depends on typing-extensions (*) which doesn't match any versions, mlc-ai-nightly-cu123 is forbidden.
So, because inference-servers depends on mlc-ai-nightly-cu123 (0.18.dev225) @ https://github.com/mlc-ai/package/releases/download/v0.9.dev0/mlc_ai_nightly_cu123-0.18.dev225-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl, version solving failed.
ceti@ceti16:~/inference-servers$ poetry add typing-extensions

Could not find a matching version of package typing-extensions


How do I install MLC-LLM with Poetry instead of Conda? - the linked page installs it with pip... What may be relevant is that it uses the --pre switch.
